# smbclient not entering smb shell

Tags: samba, smbclient

I want to access an SMB share on our intranet.

- When I execute

  ```
  smbclient -L //intranet.host/ -U myuser
  ```

  I can enter my password and get a list of all shares.
- When I want to enter the smb shell with

  ```
  smbclient //intranet.host/ -U myuser
  ```

  I'm not asked for my password and the command returns without any output.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access the shell for listing shares. You can only access the shell when actually connecting to a share.

This will work fine:

```
root@server /root $ smbclient //fqdn.local/ExistingShareName -U domain\\user
Enter domain\user's password:
Try "help" to get a list of possible commands.
smb: \>
```

This won't:

```
root@server /root $ smbclient //fqdn.local/ -U domain\\user
(returns errorcode 1)
```